# Visual Studio Expressでコード等を以前のバージョンに戻すには

Tags: visual-studio, git

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

visual studio express 2015使用しています。
画像の通り履歴から以前のバージョンにコード等を戻したいと思っています。
そこでプルが必要だと思うのですが画像画面からはそういった項目が見当たりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プル要求してみてもブラウザが立ち上がり
There are no changes to merge between the selected branches.
と表示されます。

以前のバージョンに戻すにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GITの用語と概念を理解すべきです。

GITでは各リポジトリ内に履歴があります。`pull`とはリモートリポジトリから履歴を`fetch`し、ローカルのリポジトリに`merge`する行為であって、以前のバージョンに戻す行為を指す用語ではありません。

> 以前のバージョンに戻す

一口に戻すと言っても様々な方法があります。履歴を維持したまま以前のバージョンを取得する`checkout`、履歴を含めて以前のバージョンに戻す`reset`とがあり、更に細分化されます。質問文からはどのような行為を求めているか読み取れませんでしたので、まずは[Git のさまざまなツール - リセットコマンド詳説](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%96%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E8%A9%B3%E8%AA%AC)を参照されることをお勧めします。